# Trigger UIDatePicker automatic style to be displayed

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uikit, ios14

I am building a Date Picker with this new iOS 14 style (automatic) that has this android native calendar design.

I would like to use another button than the native one to trigger this calendar, however I don't find a way to force it's shown / hidden state different than the native button.

If this can help to understand my problem I would like to do the same as the  `becomeFirstResponder()` / `resignFirstResponder()` from an `UITextField`.

Thanks in advance